# HTML form text - save data as url using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am saving the form text(facebook page name) entered by the user into to database.

```
<form:input type="text"  path="fName" value="${bean.fName}" title="Page Name"/>
```

What i want is when the user enters the fbpage name in the form text it should automatically change into fb-url. For example if user enters **"google"** the form text should change to **"https://www.facebook.com/google".** 
How can i achieve this by Javascript ?

Comment: you want to change the text value not to re-direct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello If I understand your problem that text should be change into url in the same textbox then try the below code

```
$("#user").change(function()  //user is textbox ID
{
$("#user").val("https://www.google.com/"+$("#user").val()); //added google you can use facebook also
 });
```

check below fiddle
[Url Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/r2z06hug/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text-box value :

```
<input type='text' path='fname' id='path' value="${bean.fname}" title="Page Name" onfocusout='changeValue()'/ >
```

JS :

```
function changeValue(){
 document.getElementById('path').value = "https://www.facebook.com/"+document.getElementById('path').value; 
}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/gukalenoqu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via jquery too. if you have input like below

```
<input type='text' id='url' value="" title="Page Name" onblur="getVal()"/>
```

jquery function

```
function getVal() {
   var link = "https://www.facebook.com/";
   $("#url").val(link + $("#url").val());
}
```